# sklearn : Label Propagation: what does score() function mean?

Tags: scikit-learn, label

So, I have a semi-supervised style dataset. Cutting to the chase,

Total labels : 76865

Labeled as "1" : 459

Labeled as "0" : 167

Rest: "-1"

I ran label propagation on sklearn using fit() function, on kernel='knn'. It ran good. Now, I needed the mean accuracy. I used the score() function giving it the required parameters. The output is 0.005343. What does this tell me?

I already read the documentation for score(). It uses the accuracy_score method from metrics, apparently. I saw the example there too. But there it has both the real labels and test data. But here, there is nothing like "real labels" right? So how is it finding the score anyway? Also, does this mean my mean accuracy for the propagation is 0.5%? I mean.. that bad?

Comment: When you ran your fit-method, you provided *some* labels (because of semi-supervised learning and not unsupervised-learning). These are used for the scoring-metric. And yes: it looks bad.

Comment: Wow. thanks anyway. By the way, do you happen to know any other methods or procedures where I can cross check the accuracy? I tried to find some, but I only came across score. May be some other missed my sight?